# How to get angular material breakpoints in scss?

Tags: angular-material

I use the `BreakpointObserver` from '@angular/cdk/layout' in my projects which uses pixel values for screen sizes like Breakpoints.Medium or Breakpoints.Small. How can I get these values in my scss?